# BeautifulSoup choose the table

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

On the website there are few tables. I want to choose one of them and there is my problem.
When I write:

```
g_data=soup.find_all("table",{"class":"awT votegroup votegroup7 wH episodesList"}, {"id":"sezon7"})
```

it finds me exactly only table nr 7, but when I write as following:

```
html_1=("table",{"class":"awT votegroup votegroup7 wH episodesList"}, {"id":"sezon7"})   
g_data=soup.find_all(html_1)
```

It finds all tables (from table 1 to 7). What is a different? Why second solution doesn't work? I want to use only table nr 7 and make it into a function, so I need to second solution work properly.
All code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r=requests.get("http://www.filmweb.pl/serial/Synowie+Anarchii-2008-479538/episodes#sezon7")
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content)
html_1=("table",{"class":"awT votegroup votegroup7 wH episodesList"}, {"id":"sezon7"})
g_data=soup.find_all(html_1)
print g_data
```

Answer (score 3):

You are passing in the arguments for the search incorrectly. You'd have to combine those into **one** dictionary, and not use a tuple:

```
soup.find_all("table", {"class":"awT votegroup votegroup7 wH episodesList", "id":"sezon7"})
```

This works, but only *just*; the `class` is matched against a list (as the order of classes in the `class` attribute doesn't matter); you don't need it here as you already have an `id` to match on.

Since you are looking for just the one table, use `soup.find()`:

```
soup.find("table", id="sezon7")
```

Your search was essentially looking for any element whose **name** was either `table` or `{"class":"awT votegroup votegroup7 wH episodesList"}` or `{"id":"sezon7"}`, as you only passed in a tuple for the `name` filter.

If you wanted to wrap this into a function, you can just use variables instead of string literals:

```
element_type = 'table'
element_id = 'sezon7'
soup.find(element_type, id=element_id)
```